# Chrome headless mode system tray icon right click doesn't show the menu

Tags: google-chrome

In Chrome with the  --headless option, the system tray icon doesn't show the menu when I right-click the icon. But it seems it's actually working, since I can click "exit" or something guessing the where it locates on the menu and it actually exits.

Is this a bug, or can I solve the issue changing the command line arguments or updating chrome settings perhaps?

Note: I'm on the latest Chrome. It's the stable Chrome, not the beta or dev.

The command line:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="B:\chrome" --headless=new --disable-gpu --repl --remote-debugging-port=9222 --crash-dumps-dir="B:\chrome\dumps" --silent-debugger-extension-api --enable-logging --v=0 https://example.com/
```

[image]